# What makes a dropdown menu go over other elements?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this task at work and I'm not really sure what to look for. There are these category dropdown menus at the top of the page and the powers that be have asked me to make it so that when the menus slide down, the rest of the page slides with them to make room for them, instead of the menus just going over the other elements. They're trying to be hip or something.

At any rate, I've spent like 3 hours inspecting the HTML and CSS (which I don't normally write) and cannot figure out what needs to be tweaked in order to make the other elements slide down instead of stay where they are.

The menu is like a bunch of nested divs and spans with more CSS applied than I can count. The rest of the page is all contained in one giant div which immediately follows the categories header.

What should I be looking for? I can't figure out what's making them go outside the flow of the DOM. They have a Z-index, but setting it to a low value didn't do anything.

Comment: Normally sub-menus can overlap other items because they are positioned absolutely. Try looking for `position: absoluite`. Changing it to `position: static` will probably destroy the lay out, but it does what you ask.

Comment: Try to set the z-index a negative value. If that didn't work, then try do add a `!important`right next to the value, like: `z-index: -1 !important`

Comment: @TheYaXxE Changing the z-index will not cause the item to change its positioning relative to other elements "in 2D", only in "3D" (depth). Just changing `absolute` to `static` should already do a thing or two.

Comment: [With Position Absolute](http://jsfiddle.net/3W6sP/) and [Without Position Absolute](http://jsfiddle.net/3W6sP/1/)

Comment: Do you need anything like http://jsfiddle.net/zBzz2/ .

Answer (score 0):

if I understood you right, you want the following DIV to move down if you slide?

How about giving it an absolute position and moving it accordingly in the .click event of the menue?

```
HTML:
<div id="goaway">This text needs to go</div>

CSS:
#goaway { position:absolute; top:200px; }
```

and move back afterwards. 
If you go fency you could use http://api.jquery.com/animate/.

BrG

Answer (score 0):

ideally drop downs are created using ul element hence look for the main ul container which is able to bring the hidden item on hover of your visible nav elements at first place. Now coming to you other query regarding change of the positioning from an overlay to slide down approach which pushes the page content down can be achieved once you remove position:absolute from main ul container which is hidden initially.

PS: hope I could answer your query as this is purely based on the text that you have fed above. If not then request you to share sample code.